# Josefin Sans Font not working and glitching in Blender 3D even 2.9

Tags: text-object

I need to work on a logo animation, it's just letters with the google font "Josefin Sans".
I have this glitch, i tried with more resolution preview samples, to change the offset, but it's still buggy.
Can someone help please ?
Thanks[image]

Comment: related?: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/192959/broken-custom-font-mesh/193177#193177

Answer (score 3):

TTF fonts are a bit buggy in Blender. You have two options.

[image: Buggy text]

Use another font. OTF fonts work better in Blender. This is a good option if you have a lot of text

Or convert the text to mesh and merge misplaced vertices manually. This is good if you have only a little bit text. You can convert text to mesh in **Object Mode** from **Object menu** under **Convert To** and by selecting **Mesh from Curve/Meta/Surf/Text**.

[image: Convert to Mesh]

You can merge vertices in **Edit Mode** by selecting the vertices you wish to merge and by pressing <kbd>m</kbd>. This will give you options of how you want to merge them. In this case **Merge At Center** seems like a good option.

[image: Merge vertices]

After this you can select vertices and press <kbd>f</kbd> key to fill missing faces. 4 vertices at once should be fine.

[image: Manually fixed mesh]