# Broken text after text being extruded

Tags: mesh, extrude, text-object

I'm making 3D text, I got some problem when I added some text and converted the text to mesh and extruded them, here is the step :
1.Add text
2.Converted to mesh
3.Extruded the text

Followed by the broken text screen cut[image]

I don't know why this happened, I tried to used another way by extruding the text in the object data propertied panel then converted the text to mesh, but another problem found that the top and bottom surface of the mesh is not connected the the mesh, which means a single letter consisted of 3 part, and what is the reason behind this and how to fix this

Thanks for explain to me the reason of the two issues I wrote above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to convert text or curves to mesh to extrude.

Curves converted to mesh will en up in bad topology most of the time... If there are overlapping segments then you will have errors like the ones shown on the question.

Use the **Extrude** settings in the *Geometry* section of the text controls in the properties window.

[image]

---

And please don't use photos from your phone, use screen captures, they are more readable

[image]

Comment: I want to split the text to single letters, I followed the tutorials which directed me to convert text to mesh, I want to know why and how to fix and it is good to know the reason for such issues

Comment: you can still do single letters. Curves converted to mesh will en up in bad topology most of the time... If there are overlapping segments then you will have such errors.  But refer to your "tutorials" otherwise.

Comment: related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/193762/josefin-sans-font-not-working-and-glitching-in-blender-3d-even-2-9

Comment: If you want to seperate the letters you can:

1. Add text
2. Extrude
3. Convert to mesh
4. Add the remesh modifier (sharp + octree depth <7) and apply the modifier
5. Go to edit mode, press "p" and seperate by loose parts